# jQuery rotation and transparent images

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css, image-rotation

Hi I have some images which have a jagged edge so they naturally are a gif, png etc and have transparency however i want 2 of these images to rotate in jquery and one not to, i have this code:

```
$('#slideshow ul:odd').css('background', 'url(../skin/frontend/default/getbranded/images/header/slideshowpic2.gif) no-repeat').rotate({angle:45});
$('#slideshow ul:even').css('background', 'url(../skin/frontend/default/getbranded/images/header/slideshowpic1.gif) no-repeat').rotate({angle:0});
```

i don't know why its not working in jquery, i used jqueryrotate plugin and have also tried in css3 although in css3 it works it has a white jagged stroke around the image, how can i fix this?

These are background images. http://www.getbranded.co/magento/index.php/ this is the plugin i used: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

graham

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" Could you post a demo of the problem? ex. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm I'm an author of jQueryRotate plugin and as I said you on issues page - rotating UL elements is not supported by this plugin. Its mainly created to rotate images only (to support wide range of browsers). For you it works on Chrome just because in chrome I using css3 that also can rotate any content, but if you try the same stuff in IE<9 or Firefox then you will see that this doesn't work. I planning to release new version of plugin soon that might drop some browsers support by a gain of rotating whole content, but for that I need some time for implementations/tests. Please let me know directly on a project homepage about your issues - I will try to help figure them out for you.